# How to make SSRS report for an invoice with page breakes

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I have to create an ssrs report which will be used to print invoices from database data.
In my initial attempt I created an A4 page filled with textboxes with dataset fields inside. This works great for a single page invoice for one customer.

But now I need to create a multi-page report which would list all the invoices for a certain date.
I wonder if I need to use list for this, and if it is the case, would I need to replace each textbox with a list box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a report with **1 Tablix**.
2. Couple that to a dataset containing all your *invoicenumbers*.
3. Create a *parameter* 'invoicenumber' in the existing report.
4. Place your *existing* report as a *subreport* in the *tablix*.
5. In **Rowgroups** rightclick '**Details**' and choose **Pagebreaks**.
6. Set a pagebreak '**Between each instance of a group**'.
7. Use the invoicenumber to couple the main- to the subreport.
   (left: invoicenumber, right: [@invoicenumber])
8. Run your report ;)

Comment: I'm straggling to complete the last step. Could you explain this a little bit more "Use the invoicenumber to couple the main- to the subreport. (left: invoicenumber, right: [@invoicenumber])"

Comment: Ok, rightclick on the subreport. Choose 'Subreport properties'. Doubleclick on the name of the subreport. (You do not see anything happen but just do it, it cures a nasty bug ;)  Go to 'Parameters'. Click 'Add'. Choose your parameter in the dropdownlist. Click Fx. Click 'Fields'. Doubleclick the value you want to be entered in the parameter. That should do it. Succes!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I made it work by putting a list tablix over the whole report and dragging fields and textboxes into it. Initially I wanted to put list tablix after adding the data fields and textboxes which didn't work.